# SFTP bash shell script to copy the file from source to destination

Tags: bash, shell, sftp, copying

I have created one script to copy the local files to the remote folder. The script is working fine outside of `if` condition. But when I  enclosed inside the `if` condition the `put` command is not working. It logged into the remote server using SFTP protocol and when exist it's showing the error:

> put command not found

See what is happening after executing the script:

```
Connected to 10.42.255.209.
sftp> bye
sftp.sh: line 23: put: command not found
```

Please find the below script.

```
echo -e;
echo -e "This script is used to copy the files";
sleep 2;

localpath=/home/localpath/sftp
remotepath=/home/destination/sftp/

if [ -d $localpath ]
 then
   echo -e "Source Path found"
   echo -e "Reading source path"
   echo -e "Uploading the files"
   sleep 2;

        sftp username@10.42.255.209
        put $localpath/* $remotepath

else
```

Comment: You could simplify this and use `scp`...: `scp localpath user@10.42.255.209:/remote/path/`

Comment: Maybe `sftp username@10.42.255.209 <<< "put $localpath/* $remotepath"`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a simple case such as this, you could use `scp` instad of `sftp` and specify the files to copy on the command line:

```
 scp $localpath/* username@10.42.255.209:/$remotepath/
```

But if you would rather want to issue sftp commands, then sftp can read commands from its stdin, so you can do:

```
  echo "put $localpath/* $remotepath" | sftp username@10.42.255.209
```

Or you can use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to pass data as stdin to sftp, which might be easier if you want to run several sftp commands:

```
sftp username@10.42.255.209 << EOF
put $localpath/fileA $remotepath/
put $localpath/fileB $remotepath/
EOF
```

Finally, you could place the sftp commands in a separate file, say `sftp_commands.txt` , and have sftp execute those commands using its `-b` flag:

```
 sftp -b ./sftp_commands.txt username@10.42.255.209
```

Comment: Just a minor info to add clarity. The 'here' script/document can be saved to a shell file and run using `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result using this format

```
HOST='xyz.abc.com'
USER='xyzasd'
REMOTEPATH='/var/www/data-csv/'
file_name='/tmp/sample.csv'


sftp $USER@$HOST <<EOF
cd  /var/www/data-csv/
put $file_name
EOF
```

It will ask for password if the user have a password. Otherwise this code works fine.

Comment: That's what the [answer by @nos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53761918/850848#53762033) says already.

Comment: sry when I was looking it wasnt there.

Comment: It's there since 2018.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me
for reference read https://help.oclc.org/Librarian_Toolbox/Exchange_files_with_OCLC/Upload_files_with_SFTP/40SFTP_commands?sl=en

```
uploadFileToMFT(){
sftp -P ${PORT_NO} ${HOST_NAME}@${HOST_ID} <<EOF
cd /mdm_dev05
put ${EXPORT_OUTPUT}'/'${ID}'/'${F_NAME}
quit
EOF

}
```

Comment: That's what the [answer by @nos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53761918/850848#53762033) says already.